# What are the steps to integrate HTML templates into a Next.js 13 project?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, layout, next.js13

Is there anyone can provide guidance on how to convert an HTML template that uses either Bootstrap or Tailwind CSS into a Next.js 13.4 project? I previously worked with Next.js 12, but I'm aware that the project structure has changed significantly, eliminating the need for files like _app.js and _document.js. Could you provide some insights or ideas on how to adapt and integrate these templates effectively within the updated Next.js 13.4 structure?

Googled seached a while couldnt find proper answer anywhere

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to familiarize yourself with the Next.js documentation, particularly the Next Router functionality. This will provide you with a better understanding of how routing works in Next.js App router [(https://nextjs.org/docs)]
[1](https://nextjs.org/docs)

select "using app router doc":

[image: select "using app router doc"]